# Is there something like Vue.unuse to stop using a plugin?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I created a SignalR plugin for Vue:

```js
import AxiosPlugin from "@/plugins/axios";
import { HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from "@aspnet/signalr";
import { PluginObject } from "vue";

export class SignalRPluginOptions {
}

const SignalRPlugin: PluginObject<SignalRPluginOptions> = {
    install(Vue) {
        const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("http://localhost:5100/question-hub")
            .configureLogging(LogLevel.Error)
            .build();

        let startedPromise = null;
        function start() {
            startedPromise = connection.start().catch((err) => {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                    setTimeout(() => start().then(resolve).catch(reject), 5000));
            });
            return startedPromise;
        }
        connection.onclose(() => start());

        start();
    },
};

export default SignalRPlugin;
```

which is fine to be used with: `Vue.use(SignalRPlugin);`

However, I would like to stop using when my user is logging out, but I can't find any method / function on `Vue` to achieve that (I already checked https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-use).

Is there a workaround? Or should I use something different other than a Vue plugin?

Comment: Is there any reason to make this a plugin? Maybe just an object with `start` and `stop` methods would give you what you want?

Comment: Rewrite the install  and put a reference to unlink events from connection - propagate reference through beforecreate hook. Look in vuex applyMixin method  for an example

Comment: @skirtle this is what I ended up doing (that is, a service), however wondering if there was something I missed out somewhere in the Vue documentation that would have come handy.