# How to stop using a plugin in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I installed a custom plugin in vue

```
import Plugin from 'plugin'

if (some condition)
  Vue.use(Plugin)
else
  // some code.
```

I imported the plugin and used it using Vue.use(). I wanted to use that plugin based on some condition. In the else block i dont need the plugin.

In the else block also the plugin is available if Vue.use() is executed. Is there any way that i can unset or unuse the cusom plugin?

Comment: Maybe, this is a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415676/is-there-something-like-vue-unuse-to-stop-using-a-plugin.

Comment: May be not in my case, consider i have Vuetify plugin. i wanted to use the Vuetify plugin based on some condition.